# Want any alphanumeric and underscore, dash and period to pass

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, regex, routes

In my controller, I current set a constraint that has the following regex:

```
 @"\w+"
```

I want to also allow for underscore,dash and period.

THe more effecient the better since this is called allot.

any tips?

Comment: One or more or none or more of: dash, underscore and period?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
@"[._\w-]+"
```

Answer (score 1):

`(?:\w|[-_.])+`

Will match either one or more word characters or a hyphen, underscore or period. They are bundled in a non-capturing group.

Answer (score 1):

I guess we don't really want to add the `_` to our expression here, it is already part of the `\w` construct, which would account for uppers, lowers, digits and underscore `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, and

```
[\w.-]+
```

would work just fine.

We can also add start and end anchors, if you'd wanted to:

```
^[\w.-]+$
```

#### Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"[\w.-]+";
        string input = @"abcABC__.
ABCabc_.-
-_-_-abc.
";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

#### [C# Demo](https://ideone.com/SpirPI)

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/IYAbpG/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/IYAbpG/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does the following help?
@"[\w_-.]+"

P.S. I use Rad Software Regular Expression Designer to design complex Regexes.

Answer (score 0):

@"[\w_-.]+"

im no regex guru was just a guess so verify that it works...

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `@"[\w\-._]+"` as regex since the dash might be interpreted as a range delimiter. It is of no danger with \w but if you later on add say `@` it's safer to have the dash already escaped.

There's a few suggestions that have `_-.` already on the page and I believe that will be interpreted as a "word character" or anything from "_" to "." in a range.

Answer (score 0):

Pattern to include all: `[_.-\w]+`

You can suffix the `_` `\.` and `-` with `?` to make any of the characters optional (none or more) e.g. for the underscore:

```
[_?\.-\w]+
```

but see Skurmedel's pattern to make all optional.